# Tomcat context root

Tags: tomcat, contextpath

It might be a silly question. When I run the code from eclipse the URL I hit is `http://localhost:8080/Test`.

There are some images and css and javascript in this project. I am giving the path for them as /css/test.css, /javascript/x.js and /images/test.jpg

but instead of pointing that to `http://localhost:8080/Test/images/test.jpg` it points to `http://localhost:8080/images/test.jpg`.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the context path. In JSP you can do like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/css/style.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/js/script.js"></script>
```

This: [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) fragment `${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}` will get the context path for you. So finally you'll get what you expecting.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Paulius. I have linked some images from CSS file. Will this work in that as well?

Comment: No, for css you have to do something like this to make images work: `'images/yourImage.png'` or `'../images/yourImage.png'` depending where the images are.

Comment: Can there be a single location where I make change and it affects every place.. I am asking so because I have many CSS files and many JSP's. I cannot change at each and every place.

Comment: You can put as many css and as many JSP as you want, just make sure you are properly importing them into your <head> section of JSP page.